# React mongodb Unauthorized ‘Invalid token’ response when trying to call Authorization API "401 unauthorized token"

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

**my frontend code**

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import {jwt} from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Profile({setUser}) {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
   const navigate=useNavigate()
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        // Fetch data from the protected API endpoint
        const response = await fetch('/profile', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')}`, // Assuming you store the JWT token in localStorage
          },
        });

        if (response.status === 401) {
          // Unauthorized: No valid token provided
          console.log('Unauthorized: No valid token provided');
          navigate('/login'); // Redirect to the login page
        } else if (response.status === 200) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setUserData(data);
        } else {
          // Handle unexpected errors
          console.error('Unexpected error:', response.status);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        navigate('/login'); // Redirect to the login page in case of an error
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [navigate]);
  return (
    <div>
    <form method='GET'>
      <h1>Hello user welcome on our website</h1>
      <h2>logout</h2>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Profile
```

**my backend code**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const Users = require("../model/loginUserSchema");

const Authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.jwtToken; // Corrected access to the cookie
    const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, "thisIsMyNewCourse");
    const rootUser = await Users.findOne({ _id: verifyToken._id, "tokens.token": token });

    if (!rootUser) {
      throw new Error('User not found');
    }

    req.token = token;
    req.rootUser = rootUser;
    req.userID = rootUser._id;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle authentication errors, for example:
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized: No valid token provided');
  }
};
module.exports = Authenticate;
```

here I am sharing the you my front end and backend code. in above case user can login but it cant redirect to his profile page. its back to login page. get the error 401 unauthorize:'invalid token'. token create in backend but in front end i got the error.

also rootUser is undefined in backend

Comment: Are you using express js in Backend with node js?

Comment: yes, I am useing node.js, express.js, corse, jsonwebtoken